# Do I have to use Vala to build my app to get it on the App Store?

Tags: development, vala, elementary-project

I notice they have Vala shown front and center, but I'd much rather use electron with React so I don't have to learn a whole new language. Would they accept a submission in React?

Found this:

> Your app may be written in any language, but the front-end must be a
> native Gtk3 app. Web, Electron, Qt, Java, and other non-native app
> front-ends will be rejected during the review process. A game may be
> excepted from this requirement so long as it uses native window
> decorations and is generally usable on both loDPI and HiDPI displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the critical thing is that your app follow Elementary's [Human Interface Guideline](https://elementary.io/docs/human-interface-guidelines#human-interface-guidelines)

I'd be super curious to learn whether or not Electron could create an app that conforms to these.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I need to read this through, but I believe it may just be easier to go the Vala route.